# A question about the notation of $_\lambda\varphi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, notation

I've seen such a notation.

The sequence $\left\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\cdots \lambda_n\right\}$ is given, where $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $i=1,2,3\cdots$

This sequence is given by the law of $\varphi$  of the sequence of $\lambda$ 
numbers.

There is such a notation:

$$ _\lambda\varphi(z):= \lambda_z$$ where $z\in\mathbb{Z_+}$ or $z=1,2,3\cdots$

The author says: The meaning of $_\lambda\varphi$  the sequence of $\lambda$ numbers is given by law of $\varphi$.

I have not seen this notation used before, and would like to understand:

1. is this notation commonplace, or is it peculiar to just this author?  By way of elaboration, I'm curious as to whether I would be expected to recognise this notation by people working the field if they showed it without explanation.
2. how common is it for an author to define new notation?  Am I always going to be finding new notation for things I thought I understood?

Comment: Yes; providing an author explains what their notation means they can write (within reason) whatever they like.  What do you really mean though?  Are you asking if authors can define new notation, or are you asking if this particular notation is commonplace even though you've not seen it before?

Comment: @postmortes Actually, you asked me a lot better questions than I did. Yes, I want to ask all of your questions.

Comment: best thing to do then would be to update your question with the extra ones, as comments are intended to help you refine your question to get the best answers from people :)

Comment: @postmortes  Would you like to help me with your better questions (you did in comment) ? I'd be happy to accept your edit.

Comment: I've made an edit -- if you don't like it (and you may not!) then you can roll it back to your own version, or you can edit it further

Comment: @postmortes That's exactly what I wanted to ask.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'distribution' of the lambda numbers?  Are they random?  Or just arbitrary, or even fixed by a deterministic rule?

Comment: @nomen It cannot be random because it is given by law of $\varphi$

Comment: @Elementary: This notation doesn't make any sense without more context.  $\phi(z) = \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3,\ldots$ is free in $z$ (it's not a function of $z$ in any obvious way)  What subject are you studying?

Comment: And, unfortunately, "This sequence is given by the law of φ of the distribution of lambda numbers." makes sense in the context of probability theory.  Which is why I asked if the lambdas are random.

Comment: @nomen okay I understood. I think it was wrong in my memory. I fixed.